# After latest update, laptpop can't find network devices, can't connect to wifi

Tags: wireless, updates

Using 14.04.
Worked totally fine until last night, I just let the package manager do it's thing, but after restart it will not connect with wifi or ethernet. any thoughts?

```
04:00.0 Network Controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 [8086:0888] (rev 4)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 07)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your network devices from the terminal: lspci -nn | grep -e 0200 -e 0280 Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are the respective drivers loaded?

```
lsmod | grep -e iwl -e r8169
```

If not, load them:

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
sudo modprobe r8169
```

Is the wifi blocked by the hardware switch?

```
rfkill list all
```

It appears that something has gone very wrong in the update. I suggest you reboot and get to the GRUB menu by interrupting the boot process with the SHIFT key: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2 Select Advanced options and boot into the previous kernel version, presumably 3.13.0-43-generic. When booted fully, open a terminal and remove 3.13.0-44-generic:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-44-generic
```

Reboot and do:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade
```

Reboot, presumably to x-44, and see if both devices are now working.

Once I have more information, I will edit this answer to refine the solution.

Comment: no, nothing is blocked. the drivers, the whole thing, was working fine yesterday.

Comment: lsmod | grep -e iwl -e r8169  displays nothing

Comment: sudo modprobe iwlwifi
sudo modprobe r8169 both give module not found errors

Comment: 3.13.0-44-generic

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Same issue, no change. however it does work when booting into 3.13.0-43-generic, both devices, but reinstalling 3.13.0-44-generic doesn't help it.

Comment: Let's try a slightly different approach as per my next edit above.

Comment: after reboot, it's still in X-43, but I don't mind, and everything is working again, so I am going to let it be for now. thanks!